# Join tables that are not directly connected to each other

Tags: eclipselink, jpql

I have three entities:

```
Customer
  id    pk

Address
  id    pk
  customerid 

Phone
  id    pk
  custoemrid
```

How would I join in JPQL the Address with Phone Entity via customerid without using Customer Entity.
Is it possible at all?

In normal Transact-SQL i would write:

```
select p.*
from Address a, Phone p
where a.customer = p.customerid
and a.id = 345345
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
select p from Phone p, Address a
where a.customer = p.customer
and a.id = 345345
```